# Laravel Spmphoy Mailer Email "test...0001@mailinator.com" does not comply with addr-spec of RFC 2822. error

Tags: php, laravel, email, rfc

I want to skip rfc 2822 complain of laravel anyhow. I know it is not a good practice but I need to do it anyhow. I can see exception is throwing from `vendor/symfony/mime/Address.php` in vendor.
But how can I skip this without changing the vendor file. When the laravel was using swiftmailer,  We can override creating a custom class and binding from service provider something like below.
But I am struglling how to do the same thing with Symphony Mailer in Laravel 10.

```html
class AllowNonRfcComplaintEmailValidator extends EmailValidator
{
    /**
     * 最低限、@が含まれていて、ドメインとアカウント名が含まれているメールアドレスは許可します
     * @param string          $email
     * @param EmailValidation $emailValidation
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid($email, EmailValidation $emailValidation): bool
    {
        // warningsとerrorのプロパティを埋める
        parent::isValid($email, $emailValidation);

        if (substr_count($email, '@') !== 1) {
            return false;
        }

        list($account, $domain) = explode('@', $email);

        if (strlen($account) > 0 && strlen($domain) > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

```php
Swift::init(function () {
                Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()
                    ->register('email.validator')
                    ->asSharedInstanceOf(AllowNonRfcComplaintEmailValidator::class);
            }
        );
```

How can I do this in laravel 10 with `Symphony mailer`.
Thank you in advance,